# Merge results from multiple joins into single row using postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

I'm trying use join queries to construct a single row of results which wrap the rows from joined tables into a json array.

Here is an example scheme;

```
CREATE TABLE main(id int);
INSERT INTO main values(1);

create TABLE sub1(id int, main_id int, lang int);
insert into sub1 values (1, 1, 1);
insert into sub1 values (1, 1, 2);

create TABLE sub2(id int, main_id int, lang int);
insert into sub2 values(1, 1, 1);
```

My query:

```
select main.id, 
       array_to_json(array_agg(sub1.lang)) as sub1, 
       array_to_json(array_agg(sub2.lang)) as sub2
from main
     inner join sub1 on main.id = sub1.main_id
     inner join sub2 on main.id = sub2.main_id
where main.id = 1
group by main.id
```

At the moment, this returns;

```
| id | sub1  | sub2  | 
|----|-------|-------| 
| 1  | [1,2] | [1,1] |
```

I would like the result to look like this; (This is just taking the lang from the table)

```
| id | sub1  | sub2 | 
|----|-------|------| 
| 1  | [1,2] | [1]  |
```

I have an sql fiddle here:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/60c3f/2

I've looked into using a UNION query, but that returned multiple rows and duplicate data. I'm hoping that I will be able to do this in a similar way to what I've tried above, but I'm not sure how/if it is possible?

Comment: Are you looking something like that: `array_agg(distinct sub2.lang)`?

Comment: @Albert Ah yes, I think you are right! (I am new to SQL, so it makes sense I would have missed something so simple!). Thanks! (if you want to submit an answer, I can mark as correct)

Comment: Unrelated, but: `array_to_json(array_agg(sub1.lang))` can be simplified to `json_agg(sub1.lang)`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Ah okay - thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `distinct` keyword inside array_agg to remove duplicates:

```
array_to_json(array_agg(distinct sub2.lang))
```

And as @a_horse_with_no_name suggested it can be simplified to:

```
json_agg(distinct sub1.lang)
```